# Xcode: Is there a way to change line spacing (UI Label) in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uilabel

I've got several UILabels with multiple lines of text, but the line spacing is larger than I would prefer.  Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 6, Apple added `NSAttributedString` to `UIKit`, making it possible to use `NSParagraphStyle` to change the line spacing.

To actually change it from NIB, [please see souvickcse's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19539209/456434)

Comment: Hi... Thanks.. What is the default value of the line spacing for the UILabel ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: The answer provided below is the correct answer for this

Answer (score 47):

hi this is a late reply but it may help some one line height can be change change the text from plain to attribute [image]

Comment: @souvickcse This is not work for Custom font still now.

Comment: it works well, you just need to set the label height number to 0

Answer (score 2):

Because I friggin hate using attributed text in interface builder (I always run into IB bugs), here is an extension to allow you to set line height multiple directly to a UILabel in interface builder

```
extension UILabel {

    @IBInspectable
    var lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat {
        set{

            //get our existing style or make a new one
            let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle
            if let existingStyle = attributedText?.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, at: 0, effectiveRange: .none) as? NSParagraphStyle, let mutableCopy = existingStyle.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableParagraphStyle  {
                paragraphStyle = mutableCopy
            } else {
                paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0
                paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment
            }
            paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = newValue

            //set our text from existing text
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
            if let text = self.text {
                attrString.append( NSMutableAttributedString(string: text))
                attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: self.font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            }
            else if let attributedText = self.attributedText {
                attrString.append( attributedText)
            }

            //add our attributes and set the new text
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            self.attributedText = attrString
        }

        get {
            if let paragraphStyle = attributedText?.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, at: 0, effectiveRange: .none) as? NSParagraphStyle {
                return paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple
            }
            return 0
        }
    }
```