# How to implement UILabel line spacing using xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, line-spacing

I want to align a `UILabel`'s text vertically with line spacing via *xib* in iOS, for example:

```
 hello,
 how are
 you?
```

Please help me.

Comment: @holex,I think it is possible via programatically(setLineSpacing property for NSMutableAttributedString),But i want to know how to implement same process using xib?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode: Is there a way to change line spacing (UI Label) in interface builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112657/xcode-is-there-a-way-to-change-line-spacing-ui-label-in-interface-builder)

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112657/xcode-is-there-a-way-to-change-line-spacing-ui-label-in-interface-builder

Comment: @KathiravanG,generate UILabel for each line of text..Any other way??

Comment: i did't get what you say. could you elaborate what u asking?

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is possible to adjust line spacing via xib. Click on UIlabel on xib,then change ‘text’ property type to ’Attributed’,then go through following images. Then enter new line(press ctrl-return shortcut key)and keep cursor in between two lines then adjust ‘line’ property and ‘Max Height’ property you want. My UILael text is "Hello,how are you?"

[image]

Comment: while setting text you must do myLabel.attributedText = @"My texts....".  This will not work-->myLabel.text = @"...."

Answer (score 6):

Create this simple UILabel subclass:

```
@interface CustomLabel : UILabel
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat myLineSpacing;
@end


@implementation CustomLabel

- (void)setMyLineSpacing:(CGFloat)myLineSpacing {
    _myLineSpacing = myLineSpacing;
    self.text = self.text;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = _myLineSpacing;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                                                         attributes:attributes];
    self.attributedText = attributedText;
}
```

Set `myLineSpacing` property value with IB.

[image: screenshot]

Still you cannot preview in IB, but line spacing value is in **xib**!
You can set `label.text` in your code without caring about line spacing.

**Note:**
don't make property name "`lineSpacing`".
UILabel do have undocumented lineSpacing property, and overriding that breaks something.

Comment: "Note:
don't make property name "lineSpacing". UILabel do have undocumented lineSpacing property, and overriding that breaks something."
@rintaro this really helps

Comment: Couldn't get this to work for a month. de-prioritised this feature, had character spacing, underlining etc working. Finally, on the eve of our UAT thought i would have another crack at this and came across that simple 'note' and it solved it :| what a pain that thats not more obvious. Thanks @rintaro

Answer (score 3):

*From Interface Builder:**

[image]

**Programmatically:**

**SWift 4**

Using label extension

```
extension UILabel {

    // Pass value for any one of both parameters and see result
    func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

        guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString
        if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
        } else {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
        }

        // Line spacing attribute
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Now call extension function

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How\nto\nimplement\nUILabel\nline\nspacing\nusing\nxib?"

// Pass value for any one argument - lineSpacing or lineHeightMultiple
label.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: 2.0) .  // try values 1.0 to 5.0

// or try lineHeightMultiple
//label.setLineSpacing(lineHeightMultiple = 2.0) // try values 0.5 to 2.0
```

Or using label instance (Just copy & execute this code to see result)

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How\nto\nimplement\nUILabel\nline\nspacing\nusing\nxib?"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40

// Line spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

// Character spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

label.attributedText = attrString
```

Answer (score -8):

Type it exactly the same way you desire in any text editor like TextEdit etc and then paste in the text section of your label in xib.

**But make sure** height of your label is more to fit the content and also increase the number of lines. For this case it can be 3 or more.

[image]

Comment: how to increase line space between "hello" and "This is"?

Comment: @user Just add space in the text in TextEdit and paste it here. You can't edit the text directly in Xib. So type it in a text editor exactly how you want and then paste in the text section of your Xib.